# How to specify a field name in an entity in jhipster

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I have an existing database that I am using with jhipster, The issue is that I have a field named country_iso2 but it seems jhipster adds another underscore just before the number i.e country_iso_2. I have specified the column name in my dto class. Below is my entity

```
entity Documenttypes(document_types) {
name String required maxlength(255),
status Integer required,
countryIso2 String maxlength(2),
createdAt Instant required,
createdBy Integer
}
```

And this is my DTO class

```
public class DocumenttypesDTO implements Serializable {

private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(max = 255)
private String name;

@NotNull
private Integer status;

@Size(max = 2)
@Column(name="country_iso2")
private String countryIso2;


@NotNull
private Instant createdAt;

private Integer createdBy;

//Getters and setters
}
```

When the code is Run I get the below error

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'documentty0_.country_iso_2' in 'field list'

How then can I specify the field in the database inside the jhipster project so as not to have this issue.

Comment: Below is how the entity fields looks like in sql

id name status country_iso2 created_at created_by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was changing the column in the wrong class. The correct class is located in the com.****.****.domain Package.
In that class you can be able to specify the column name.

I was able to change from the code below:

```
@Size(max = 2)
@Column(name = "country_iso_2", length = 2)
private String countryIso2;
```

To the below code:

```
@Size(max = 2)
@Column(name = "country_iso2", length = 2)
private String countryIso2;
```